# unity resources subfolders not accessable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a simple code that im trying to use to access saves in json. my folder structure is
[image: file structure]

and the files are in the tim folder. my code is `TextAsset o = Resources.Load<TextAsset> ("saves/tim/basics");`
and o is `null`. i then tried moving basics.json out of the tim folder so it is just in the saves folder, and then changed the code to `TextAsset o = Resources.Load<TextAsset> ("saves/basics");`, and that worked returned a textAsset. is this something im doing wrong, or just a limitation of unity?

Comment: Please put a screenshot of where you put the file in the subfolder and I will tell you what you did wrong

Comment: Closed since this is a typo. The duplicate mentioned that this should the named "Resources" not "Resource".

Comment: okay, the folder was named correctly, just the s got cut off of the snipping tool, but now i just tried again, and it worked.

Comment: Well, I wonder why you would upload a screenshot of cut-off folder when the names are the main reason I wanted to see it. Glad you got it working.  I advice you to use `Resources.LoadAsync` instead. You can find it at the end of the answer from the duplicate.